# Removing borders from Bootstrap accordion

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on constructing Bootstrap accordion menus and I am trying to hide the border that displays when it is collapsed and when it is opened. Here is the code I have so far:

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
      <button style="font-weight: bold; background-color: #f5f5f5;"class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        Tester
       </button>
  <div id="collapseOne"class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-body" style="background-color: #f5f5f5;">
      Placeholder text
  </div>
```

```
 .accordion-button:not(.collapsed) {
    color: black  !important;
    background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
  }
.accordion-button:link, .accordion-button:visited, .accordion-button:hover, .accordion-button:active  {
    background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
    color: black !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    border: hidden !important;
    border-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
    box-shadow: 0px !important;

  }
  
  .accordion-button:focus {
    z-index: 3;
    border-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .25rem #f5f5f5 !important;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }

  .accordion-body {
    border-bottom: none !important;
  }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

https://jsfiddle.net/y8va5j3L/

Your edited CSS:

```
    color: black  !important;
    background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
  }
.accordion-button:link, .accordion-button:visited, .accordion-button:hover, .accordion-button:active  {
    background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
    color: black !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    border: none;
    border-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
    box-shadow: 0px !important;

  }
  
  .accordion-button {
    border: none;
  }
  
  .accordion-button:focus {
    z-index: 3;
    border-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .25rem #f5f5f5 !important;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }

  .accordion-body {
    border-bottom: none !important;
  }


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/y8va5j3L/
```